# Vaadin: trigger menuitem click

Tags: java, vaadin

Is there any way to simulate that a **[MenuItem](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/MenuBar.MenuItem.html)** has been clicked in Vaadin, for e.g. testing purposes? I can't seem to find any way to do this.

Ideally I'd want to be able to do this through the Vaadin framework, e.g. something along the lines of:

```
theMenuItem.click();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no direct way of simulating a click, but try the following to simulate selection and checking of a MenuItem:

```
    MenuItem mi = null; // TODO

    // Selection
    if (null != mi.getCommand()) {
        mi.getCommand().menuSelected(mi);
    }

    // Toggle checked
    if (mi.isCheckable()) {
        mi.setChecked(!mi.isChecked());
    }
```

Also, I suggest you to decouple the Menu from navigation from UI implementation to make the navigation better testable using JUnit.

Answer (score 0):

For testing, you can use the java.awt.Robot.class in Java, or use a test HIM API

Comment: Can you describe, if possible, how you would do this using Vaadin?

Comment: @Andiaz I've do not done this with Vaadin, but you can click on a point of the screen with Robot, so, for test, you have to know where tabs are dispached, and then, click on them with the Robot.

Comment: Ah, so it's pixel based? Does it handle e.g. different resolutions or is it based on the resolution of the person running the tests? It sounds interesting, but ideally I'd like to be able to do this from the Vaadin framework itself. I updated my question a bit to reflect upon this.

Comment: You certainly have some response in https://vaadin.com/forum, oif not you can post an answer

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend decoupling the Menu from your navigation.  We use guava's EventBus to ensure a separation of concerns, and make testing easier.